# SWIFT routing codes for all global banks

Tags: data-request, finance, global, bank

Does anyone know if it's possible to get [SWIFT routing codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9362) for all banks, or only on a per-country basis?

---

*(this came up in my [Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/pudo/status/737378338755489793) - I thought it was a good question and I didn't find any easily usable data already available.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of paid API services that allow such requests. Trying to advertise commercial offerings as little as possible, I can mention the original [SWIFT API](https://www.swift.com/our-solutions/interfaces-and-integration/swift-apis).

You could probably also scrape data from [this site](https://www.theswiftcodes.com/). I've been using [another one](https://bank.codes/swift-code/) that allows up to 20 free requests a day. However, these two, and possibly any other services might not guarantee to have all jurisdictions and all banks present. This is mostly due to the regional particularities of nomenclature that result in associations that might appear sometimes strange and not following an algorithmic approach.