# public list of world banks

Tags: data-request, bank

I don't need branch offices and full addresses.

I think of data ... XML, CSV ... with these fields :

- bank code, as used in [SWIFT BIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9362)
- bank name
- country name or country code (ISO two letters)
- optional : city of bank headquarters

For each bank, one record per country of presence.

If there are other bank codes, of widespread usage, it is good.

Comment: You can see that on this website: https://www.theswiftcodes.com/. You can crawl the data from this site if needed.

Comment: @JafferWilson I don't want to crawl web pages

Comment: Consider [this answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/15247/20652) that I've just provided to a very similar question.