# List of the banks worldwide

Tags: data-request, bank

Could you guys help me to find a dataset with a list of the banks worldwide (or list of **European banks** at least). Doesn't matter which format it will be (JSON, XML, SQL). The main problem: I need a banks list with SWIFT/BIC and (the most important thing) with **an internal country codes**: eg, for Germany it's 8 numbers code (like 37040044), for Czech Republic - 6 numbers (like 0800), for France - 5 numbers (like 20041).

Comment: I think it's an [exact duplicate](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/7902/1511), but unfortunately no answers

Comment: also, see this comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11105/public-list-of-world-banks#comment14441_11105

Comment: @philshem not exactly duplicate, because I am not seeking a SWIFT list, but list of the domestic bank codes. For example, in Germany it's call "BLZ" (Bankleitzahl): http://finaint.com/BLZ-List/100.html , so it's not the same as SWIFT/BIC

Comment: Domestic bank codes are present in IBAN information, so indeed not really related to SWIFT. Anyway, I've just responded the other question, and the argument is even stronger, as there's even more variation in IBAN.